# C# - Unflagging Database Values In The Event Of Console App Crash

Tags: c#, database, linq, console-application

I currently have a c# console app where multiple instances run at the same time.  The app accesses values in a database and processes them. While a row is being processed it becomes flagged so that no other instance attempts to process it at the same time. My question is what  is a efficient and graceful way to unflag those values in the event an instance of the program crashes? So if an instance crashed I would only want to unflag those values currently being processed by that instance of the program.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential solution will depend heavily on how you start the console applications.

In our case, the applications are started based on configuration records in the database. When one of these applications performs a lock, it uses the primary key from the database configuration record to perform the lock.

When the application starts up, the first thing it does is release all locks on the records that it previously locked.

To control all of the child processes, we have a service that uses the information from the configuration tables to start the processes and then keeps an eye on them, restarting them when they fail.

Each of the processes is also responsible for updating a status table in the database with the last time it was available with a maximum allowed delay of 2 minutes (for heavy processing). This status table is used by sysadmins to watch for problems, but it could also be used to manually release locks in case of a repeating failure in a given process.

If you don't have a structured approach like this, it could be very difficult to automatically unlock records unless you have a solid profile of your application performance that would allow you to know that any lock over 5 minutes old is invalid because it should only take, on average, 15 seconds to process a record with a maximum of 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle any kind of crash, even power off I would suggest to timestamp records additionally and after some reasonable timeout treat records as unlocked even if they are flagged.